Special key not working in Ubuntu
I am new to Ubuntu (Linux in general). I use a laptop and the right-click of my mousepad is dead, so I used to use a "special key" provided on my laptop for the same usage, It used to work in Windows 10.
I did as much as I could, I checked the input that the system is getting when the key is pressed with xev but it gives out this.
state 0x0, keycode 60 (keysym 0x2e, period), same_screen YES

which is exactly the same as the period button. I think it recognizes it as a period button.
Device: Lenovo Thinkpad 80MJ (old from 2014-15). The key is between right Alt and Ctrl.


Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please mention the OS version by editing your question.

and what is the output of Shift+F10?
